# My command to create a scatter plot in R did not work

Tags: r

I was watching the tutorial of creating a scatter plot with R studio
of the dataset "Iris". I was using the code from the tutorial but got errors.
My code was as below:

```
scatterplot(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length|Species, data=iris, xlab="Sepal Width",
            ylab="Sepal.Length", main="Iris Data", labels=row.names(iris))
```

The error messages are as below:

> Error in axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
>   'labels' is supplied and not 'at' In addition: Warning messages: 1: In
>   plot.window(...) : "labels" is not a graphical parameter 2: In
>   plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "labels" is not a graphical parameter

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated:)

Comment: It is difficult to say what went wrong without knowing more about the `scatterplot` function.  From the warning message,  it seems to relate to the argument `labels`.

Comment: As the error message said `"labels" is not a graphical parameter`.  If you simply remove the part of your code that says `labels=row.names(iris)` your code will work. I am not quite sure what you wanted to accomplish with the labels part, but this will get you started.

Comment: BTW,  you apparently used the `car` package to get the function `scatterplot`. It would be helpful for people here if you included the statement `library(car)` in your code so that we don't have to figure out what packages you are using.